# React lazy loading stuck re rendering components

Tags: reactjs

Trying to lazy load some components using React's lazy except the specific component required is continuously re-rendered lagging the browser and still only showing the fallback component.

NB. The suspense tags are in a parent component

Code:

```
const Lesson = () => {

const [graphics, setGraphics] = useState(<Graphics source="" />);

let { id } = useParams();

const Lesson1 = lazy(()=> import("./Lesson 1/Lesson.js")) ;
const Lesson2 = lazy(()=> import("./Lesson 2/Lesson.js")) ;
const Lesson3 = lazy(()=> import("./Lesson 3/Lesson.js")) ;
const Lesson4 = lazy(()=> import("./Lesson 4/Lesson.js")) ;

const getLesson = () => {
    switch (id) {
        case "1":
            return <Lesson1 setGraphics={setGraphics}/>
        case "2":
            return <Lesson2 setGraphics={setGraphics}/>
        case "3":
            return <Lesson3 setGraphics={setGraphics}/>
        case "4":
            return <Lesson4 setGraphics={setGraphics}/>
        default:
            return;

    }
}

return (
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
    <div className="min-vh-100">
        <CustomNavbar />
        <div className="min-vw-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100 align-items-center">
            <ListGroup horizontal variant="flush" className="justify-content-center h-100 align-items-center w-100" style={{minHeight: "90vh"}}>
                <ListGroup.Item className="h-100 w-100" style={{maxWidth: "50vw", border: "0"}}>
                    <LessonCard id={id}/>  
                        {getLesson()}
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item className="h-100 w-100" style={{maxWidth: "50vw", border: "0"}}>
                    {graphics}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    </DndProvider>
    
)}
```